# djangorestframework:get the value with manytomanyfield

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new in django rest framework
I have questionabout how to get the relation value with ManyToManyField

Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

class MovieTheater(models.Model):
    movietheater = models.ManyToManyField(Movie,null=True,blank=True,through="MovieShowtime")
    movie_theater = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)     
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)     

class MovieShowtime(models.Model):
    theater = models.ForeignKey( MovieTheater, null=True,blank=True,related_name = 'theater' )
    movie = models.ForeignKey( Movie, null=True,blank=True,related_name = 'movie' )
    time = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
```

**serialize.py**

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('link', 'title')

class MovieShowtimeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movieid = serializers.CharField(source='movie_id')   
    theaterid = serializers.CharField(source='theater_id')  

    class Meta:
        model = MovieShowtime
        fields = ('movieid', 'theaterid','time' )       

class TheaterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movieintheater = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True,source='movietheater', view_name='movie_detail')
    time = MovieShowtimeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='theater')

    class Meta:
        model = MovieTheater
        fields = ('movieintheater','time','tel' )
```

views.py

```
class TheaterList(object):
    queryset = MovieTheater.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TheaterSerializer
```

and when I go to  `url(r'^theaters/$', TheaterList.as_view())`

The results is like:

```
{
    "movieintheater": [
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/movies/159", 
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/movies/160", 

    ], 
    "time": [
        {
            "movieid": 159, 
            "theaterid": 3, 
            "time": "12 : 50 PM | 06 : 20 PM"
        }, 
        {
            "movieid": 160, 
            "theaterid": 3, 
            "time": "12 : 40 PM | 04 : 50 PM | 09 : 00 PM"
        },      
    ], 
    "tel": "1234567890"
},
```

I want to know how to show the value like this:
directly replace the number(movieid,theaterid) into the model's info
Please teach me. Thank you

```
    {
    "movieintheater": [
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/movies/159", 
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/movies/160",  
    ], 
    "time": [
        {
            "movieid.title": 'movie1', 
            "theaterid": 3, 
            "time": "12 : 50 PM | 06 : 20 PM"
        }, 
        {
            "movieid.title": 'movie2', 
            "theaterid": 3, 
            "time": "12 : 40 PM | 04 : 50 PM | 09 : 00 PM"
        },      
    ], 
    "tel": "1234567890"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `source` of fields in Django REST Framework can span relations, so you can get a property of a related object and use it for a field.

```
class MovieShowtimeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(source='movie.title')   
    theaterid = serializers.CharField(source='theater_id')  

    class Meta:
        model = MovieShowtime
        fields = ('movieid', 'theaterid','time', )
```

You must use the dotted path as the `source`, so `movie.title` will get you the `title` of the related `movie`. You may be interested in more fields though, in which case you are probably better of just [nesting another serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26867635/359284), like you have already done for the show times.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can move on now!